# How to include Bootstrap JavaScript into React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I would like to use bootstrap for my web app, I have already included css successfully but I am having difficulties include Bootstrap JavaScript for showing modals, alerts etc.

In my package.json I have the following: **"bootstrap": "^4.2.1",** and in index.js I have smth like this:

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
```

and in my html I have the following:

```
<div className="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                           asdasdasd
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Error I am getting is:

*Module not found: Can't resolve 'jquery' in 'C:\Users\iluli\Desktop\Work\atop\atop\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js'*

How else I can include bootstrap js on my react app.

Comment: You need to include jQuery as well.

Comment: if I have choose to work with React why would I still need jQuery? is it possible that I can use react without jQuery?

Comment: @Mizlul you can use react without jquery. You cannot use Bootstrap.js without jquery

Comment: Bootstrap requires jQuery. So it doesn't matter if you use react or any other thing.

Comment: I see, how then can I fix it, by just running smth like npm install jquery?

Comment: Yes, install jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library that includes it for you like [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)

Beyond that it will solve the problem you mentioned there are other advantages to use such a library and not directly the code from bootstrap.
for exmple, this code:

```
 <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
      <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
      <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
      <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
        <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">GitHub</NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
            <DropdownToggle nav caret>
              Options
            </DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu right>
              <DropdownItem>
                Option 1
              </DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem>
                Option 2
              </DropdownItem>
              <DropdownItem divider />
              <DropdownItem>
                Reset
              </DropdownItem>
            </DropdownMenu>
          </UncontrolledDropdown>
        </Nav>
      </Collapse>
    </Navbar>
```

Seems much more readable and in "react way" than this code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

you better use this library and not [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) Despite its popularity because it's not supported v4 yet and there [pr](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/2752) for this is without any news for a long time

Comment: I have already choosen a library , is it possible to include with the current library?

Comment: you will include only react-bootstrap and it will include all the necessary thing for you - bootstrap, jquery and all the thing you need - after it you will work on react in the usual way but you will have bootstrap in your app

Comment: It doesn't support Bootstrap v4 which the OP uses